# Cannot resize the image in HTML page using bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Cannot resize the image in my webpage. images are displayed in full size. I am using Bootstrap 4 carousel component. But the images seem to be non-responsive.

```css
.carousel-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

The corresponding carousel part is as follows:
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="10000">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car4-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car2-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car3-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify the img attribute if you want to resize the image:

```css
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="10000">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car4-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car2-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="{% static 'images/car3-carousel.jpg' %}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>



<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="10000">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590948616180-fbe9e1fa7eaf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="2000">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590948616180-fbe9e1fa7eaf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590948616180-fbe9e1fa7eaf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem is, I cannot resize it according to my need. I need it's width 100% and height should be half of the original image. Image's width is fine but the height is not getting changed.

Comment: I get it, sorry for misunderstanding please see the  edited `snippet`

Comment: You can simply change `height` of your `image` according to your need. the edited snippet have height of `50vh` which is equal to the half of the screen!

Comment: Yes, now the image is displaying half of the original, but its now getting cropped. Cannot see the complete image.

Comment: Well you can remove  `object-fit: cover` from `css` then the complete image will be shown the only disadvantage you will face that it will make your `image` looks ugly and stretched  see this: https://jsfiddle.net/1rdma978/1/

Comment: Problem now solved. Kept the object-fit, but changed it's value to fill. it makes the image ugly; so increased the height to 80vh. Now almost ok, although not perfect.

Comment: Is there any treat for my answer exist if it help you a little bit?

Comment: Sorry. It's certainly helped.